# Angular CLI + Angular 4 = IE10 doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I can't get IE10 to load a brand new Angular CLI project. There is no other code other than what comes with default Angular CLI package when you run 'ng new'.

I'm using Angular 4.2.4, @angular/cli 1.3.1 and IE 10.0.9200.16519

I have tried 'ng build' and 'ng build --prod' and both return the same error messages. The project runs on every other browser.

I have uncommented all polyfill lines (and installed everything as per instructions in the file) that are needed to run IE9, IE10, IE11 in the polyfills.ts of the project.

The 4 errors are:

**Expected identifier polyfills.bundle.js, line 6127 character 67**

```
var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = typeof Symbol === "function" && Symbol.for && Symbol.for("react.element") || 0xeac7;
```

**Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' styles.bundle.js, line 279 character 3**

```
update = applyToSingletonTag.bind(null, styleElement, styleIndex, false);
```

**Expected identifier vendor.bundle.js, line 2056 character 71**

```
exports.rxSubscriber = (typeof Symbol === 'function' && typeof Symbol.for === 'function') ?
Symbol.for('rxSubscriber') : '@@rxSubscriber';
```

**Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty' main.bundle.js, line 132 character 1**

```
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Seems like '**Symbol**', '**bind**', and '**defineProperty**' are the culprits.

I do see Symbol and Object es6 polyfills being included in the pollyfills.ts project file though:

```
****************************************
* BROWSER POLYFILLS
*/
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
...
(+ all the other polyfills that are in the polyfills.ts file)
```

How do I get this going on IE10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

to `<head>` section of index.html.

Setting IE9,IE10,IE11 compatibility mode to EDGE fixed all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

By default angular cli project doesn't unable polyfills which required for angular application to run on IE9, IE10 and IE11. We need to uncomment all required polyfills present under `src/polyfills.ts` it in order to run application on IE. (Make sure your have installed all instructed node packages like `classlist.js`, `web-animations-js` & `intl` using `npm install --save command.)

Comment: My bad, but for your second comment, I already did editing to my answer before reading your first comment.