# Aurelia: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' in IE 11

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, aurelia

**The problem**

I am trying to get my Aurelia project working in Internet Explorer 11, however, I am getting the following message:

Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' (app.bundle.js 188,11)

The rule that causes this error:

```
    var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);
```

This issue is happening when I am trying to bundle my application by building it with:

```
    au build --env dev
```

**What have I tried**

I have done some research and found out that more people had similar issues, but not a lot with exactly the same one as me. Also, I saw that Polyfill is able to solve a couple of these issues, but at their documentation, I saw nothing about bind.

I would appreciate any help and do not hesitate to ask for more information!

Comment: Array.push ? should be a method, .bind next 2 looks strange in standard JS ?

Comment: @Tom I agree but that file is auto-generated by the building/bundling process of Aurelia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` [is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) by IE since IE 9. Maybe you triggered other IE modes than IE 11.

You could try to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in `<head>` section of html. I also found two similar threads you could refer to: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449861/angular-cli-angular-4-ie10-doesnt-work), [thread 2](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11384).

If the issue still persists, you could provide [a minimal code sample to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hmm, I am not the only one who has the issue. However, the meta tag did not fix it for me.

Comment: Could it be that I should add some Polyfills in order to make it work? If so, which ones should I add?

Comment: Your answer was quite alright actually. But it is worth mentioning that you have to use that meta tag as your first meta tag, otherwise, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened because Compatibility View was default enabled in Internet Explorer 11.
To ignore this, you can add the meta tag that Yu Zhou posted, this has to be the FIRST meta tag in the head section:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```