# Angular 10 is not Supporting IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, angular10, ie11-developer-tools

My Angular 10 application is not working on IE11. It is working from my localhost after making below changes. When I use build ng build --base-href --configuration=es5.
On IE11 it was showing blank page with these errors.
[image]

Update:

After adding the meta tag

I was getting the below error.
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment
[image]

Step-1:
Added tsconfig-es5.app.json file

```
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5"
}
```

}

Step-2: Removed not in browserlist

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
 IE 9-10 # Angular support for IE 9-10 has been deprecated and will be removed as of Angular 
 v11. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
 IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

Step-3: In polyfills.ts file
Uncomented these import and installed it using npm

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */



/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/promise';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */
  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
//   (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
//   (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
//   (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
  (window as any).global = window;
  

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

import 'core-js';
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 
*/
import 'hammerjs/hammer';
```

step-4:This is my angular.json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "employeelogin": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/employeelogin",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "es5": {
              "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
          },
            "int": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.int.ts"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": false
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": false
            },
            "lab": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.lab.ts"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": false
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build:development"
            },
            "es5": {
              "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build:es5"
            },
            "lab": {
              "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build:lab"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build:dev"
            },
            "int": {
              "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build:int"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "employeelogin:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "employeelogin:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "employeelogin:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "employeelogin"
}
```

Comment: I take it you read everything to do with IE11 [here](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aurelia: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344215/aurelia-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-bind-in-ie-11)

Comment: You could try using the `--aot` flag if you're not already using AOT

Comment: Not sure if that fixes the issue, but you should use [differential loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) by setting tsconfig's target to `es2015`. The CLI will then produce both ES5 bundles for IE, and ES2015 bundles for modern browsers.

Comment: @Keith Updated the error  with a Screenshot after adding the Meta tag in index.html file